# Visual Studio - Exception deserializing the package

Tags: ssis, ssdt-2017

I am getting following error while executing a package in Visual Studio.
[image: Exception deserializing the package].

What could be causing this. Has anyone encountered same or similar issue?

I checked my other packages in my project which are in the same path and they are executing successfully.

Answer (score 0):

It happens. Something in Visual Studio is holding on to the ispac from your project. Debugging a Project Deployment model SSIS package involves

- compiling all the packages into an ispac
- running the package from the ispac (to pick up project level parameters, connection managers, etc)

The quickest way to resolve the issue is to change your project from Debug to Release

[image]

Right click on project to rebuild

Switch back to Debug

Otherwise, if you want to get fancy, grab ProcessExplorer from Microsoft's Sysinternals site and find the offending process (likely DtsDebugHost)

https://billfellows.blogspot.com/2013/04/file-in-use-by-another-process.html